# find a string in a text file in a batch script

Tags: batch-file

I have to read a text file rtcponactive.txt .the file contains below lines

```
operationalState                     1 (ENABLED)
rtcpBearerSupervisionTimerAoIp       0
rtcpBearerSupervisionTimerNb         15
rtcpBearerSupervisionTimerVoip       15
rtcpOnNbActive          

         true
```

I have to find a line which matches rtcpOnNbActive true and want to store it in to a variable.
please how to write a batch script.

Comment: start with `find /?` and `findstr /?`. I assume, `true` should be in one line with `rtcpOnNbActive`? If you have trouble with your code, edit your question with your code.

Comment: I answered the question because it seems, that you have no clue where to start.

Answer (score 0):

use `find` or `findstr` to get the wanted line (I assume, "true" is on the same line than "rtcpOnNbActive"):

```
find "rtcpOnNbActive" rtcponactive.txt
```

to put the response into a variable, use `for`:

```
for /f "delims=" %%i in  ('find "rtcpOnNbActive" rtcponactive.txt') do set variable=%%i
```

`"delims="` tells it, you want the complete line.

If you want to get "true" or "false" only, use:

```
for /f "tokens=2" %%i in  ('find "rtcpOnNbActive" rtcponactive.txt') do set variable=%%i
```

`"tokens=2"`means, "take the second value of the line". Space and Tab are standard delimiters, so you don't need `delims=..."` here.

Note: if there are more than one line containing "rtcpOnNbActive", it will return the last one.